# Detect SCNNode with camera only

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

Let's say I draw a circle in the middle of my screen, to use it as a target. If I point this circle to a node, how is it possible for ARKit to detect it?

For now I'm using the tap method

```
 @IBAction func tapHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let viewTouchLocation:CGPoint = sender.location(in: sceneView)
    guard let result = sceneView.hitTest(viewTouchLocation, options: nil).first else {
        return
    }
    // ...etc
}
```

which works really well, but it would be so much better to detect a node just by pointing the camera at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let screenRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenRect.size.width
let screenHeight = screenRect.size.height

let location = CGPoint(x:screenWidth/2,y:screenHeight/2)
```

use location in hittest

Comment: Ok so I just need to trigger the hitTest every time the camera moves. Any idea which event it could be?

Comment: func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) . it gets called every frame.